# Rule of function calculating

Tags: functions

Equation is
 $$ f(x+5) = (x-1)^2 $$
Then substitute $ x = -4 $. 
In this case what is the result?
$ f(x+5) $ is $0$, or $25$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What do you think the correct result is? Moreover, $f(x+5)$ will never be just a number, it depends on $x$. $f(1)$ can be a number though

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $x = -4$ means *all* instances of $x$ should be swapped with $-4$. That means
$$
f(\color{red}{x}+5) = (\color{red}{x} - 1)^2\\
f(\color{red}{-4}+5) = (\color{red}{-4}-1)^2\\
f(1) = (-5)^2 = 25 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$f(x+5)=(x-1)^2$$ Now setting $x=-4$, we get

$$f(-4+5)=(-4-1)^2$$
$$\iff f(1)=(-5)^2=25$$